# Does kube-proxy creates a NodePort everytime a new Node is added in the cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have a working cluster with services and PODS/replicas running. 
If I an not wrong, if a service is created with Type=NodePort/LoadBalancer, Kube-proxy creates a new NodePort in all the nodes and creates a iptable rule.
If I add a new Node to the cluster, does Kube-proxy creates a NodePort in the newly added Node also?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. That's what kubeproxy is meant to do.